# JSON coming back undefined on AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I'd like to return JSON data for the object I just created through an .ajax() callback, but it keeps coming back undefined which makes me believe I'm doing something wrong in my create action. Here it is:

```
def create 

    ajax_title = params[:title]
  ajax_content = params[:content]
  ajax_folder = params[:folder_id]
  ajax_parent = params[:parent_id]
  ajax_children = Array(params[:children])

  @submission = Submission.find_by_title(ajax_title)

  if ajax_title && @submission
      @submission.content = ajax_content
      @submission.save
  else
      @submission = Submission.create(
          :title=>ajax_title,
          :content=>ajax_content, 
          :user_id=>current_user.id, 
          :folder_id=>ajax_folder,
          :parent_id=>ajax_parent, 
          :children=>ajax_children,
      )
  end

respond_to do |format|
  if @submission.save
    format.json { render :json => @submission.to_json }
  else
    format.json { :errors => @submission.errors }
  end
end

end
```

At the bottom you'll see where I'm trying to render it. Here's my AJAX PUT request:

```
entryAJAX = function(){
  $("#entry-button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "/submissions",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {folder_id: <%= @folder.id %>},
    complete: function(data){
    console.log(data.id);         
      }
            });
  });      
};
```

I know the routes and create action work since the model instances are created successfully, so any idea why the data is coming back undefined?

Comment: Should `complete` be `success`?

Comment: Actually changing it from `complete` to `success` worked, oddly enough.

Comment: I suspect this is because complete doesn't actually receive the data object